# Unable to sort in asc order for a custom methods(column) in elasticsearch

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch

```
module Indexing
    def as_indexed_json(options={})
      self.as_json({
        include: { data: { only: [:some_data] } },
        methods: [:method_one, :method_two, :method_three]
        })
    end
  end
```

method_two is the string column.

Unable to sort in asc order using method_two column using elasticsearch model but samething works fine in desc order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue earlier.

You just need to add an index to the column in your mapping

```
mapping do
  indexes :method_two, type: :string, index: :not_analyzed
end
```

Comment: This is custom method/column so do I need to add that explicitly to index ?

Comment: Yes, you can index a custom method too.

Comment: do we have to reindex after doing this? because this is not working for me.